# Corda V3 Network Permissioning self issuance of node certificates

Tags: corda

Hi I have been trying non-dev mode to start up the nodes for corda V3.

Currently after starting the node, during **restart** I am experiencing an error of: `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The issuing certificate for C=UK, L=London, O=NetworkMapAndNotary has role NETWORK_MAP, expected one of [INTERMEDIATE_CA, NODE_CA]`

the roles that I followed is provided in this link: https://docs.corda.net/head/permissioning.html#certificate-role-extension

obtained from `OID Corda Role (1.3.6.1.4.1.50530.1.1)`

Any pointers for this issue?

When i followed Devmode and assign my NetworkMapAndNotary to (Role 4) it fails to startup with the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect cert role: NODE_CA at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkMapKt.verifiedNetworkMapCert(NetworkMap.kt:48) ~[corda-node-api-corda-3.0.jar:?]`

on a side note: i tried to follow devmode cert creation and noticed that the devmode (NetworkMapAndNotary) cert is tagged under a node ( role 4 ) why is that so..

```
Certificate[2]:
Owner: O=NetworkMapAndNotary, L=London, C=UK
Issuer: C=UK, L=London, OU=corda, O=R3, CN=Corda Node Intermediate CA
Serial number: 39551bff61207fb6
Valid from: Mon Mar 26 07:00:00 ICT 2018 until: Thu May 20 07:00:00 ICT 2027
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  D1:8C:4D:83:F2:A7:F4:DA:60:05:E3:69:2C:30:FF:20
     SHA1: E5:4D:01:A5:68:01:73:59:8B:7A:3D:0B:28:4E:35:C4:CD:DE:C7:52
     SHA256: 3F:D6:24:E5:C8:9F:BE:EE:D4:99:D7:2C:85:50:F0:A8:26:46:84:D7:FB:3A:42:54:F2:12:64:51:48:58:FD:CF
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withECDSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.4.1.50530.1.1 Criticality=false
0000: 02 01 04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by assigning two different certificates by following this diagram: https://docs.corda.net/_images/certificate_structure.png

Basically I need to create two certs instead of one.

1. self sign certificate for network map ( network map role )
2. another signed certificate for nodeca ( node role )

An issue here was because of Corda's tool `networkBootStrapper.kt` file comes with a hard code function inside the function of: `installNetworkParameters` where it will always call: `createDevNetworkMapCa()` function to generate a dev key pair regardless if I am in dev-mode or not.

Customize the file to use the self-signed certificate for network map adding on the role-extension. so the node certificate still remains but the network Map will be a one-time used key just to generate the network-parameters file for each nodes, the node role will always be used for node startup.

It was failing restart because it was seeing that there was a networkmap role certificate acting as another node role in the network.

Answer (score 0):

The Network Map has been redesigned in Corda V3. Take a look at the following [blog post](https://medium.com/corda/re-designing-the-network-map-760f62ae8c62) and the docs [here](https://docs.corda.net/head/network-map.html)

Try removing the Network Map identity

Comment: Yes I am aware of the following. as stated i am using V3, and this error occurs during restart of a node in non dev mode, networkMapAndNotary implementations is also from V3.